# how to use limit and count in Odoo Api post call

Tags: api, count, limit, odoo

I want to get the total number of matching records and from that records, I want only limited records like 10 out of 1000 and so on, for pagination of the large volume of entry.

I try like this,

```
  {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "params": {
    "model": "zb.jason.controller",
    "method": "list_items_detailed",
    "args": [
      {
        "limit": 1,

        "model": "crm.lead",
        "conditions": "[]",
        "fields": "[ 'contact_name', 'company_id','source_id','date_open', 'description', 'product_id', 'date_closed', 'probability',  'team_id','professions_id','phone','type_of_operation','is_corporate','partner_id','email_from','phone','date_deadline','religion','age_bucket','pro_info','medium_id','user_id','team_id','partner_name','street','street2','zip','district_id','state_id' ,'decision_maker' , 'locations_id','website','contact_name','function','dob','profession_id','spouse_dob','anniversary_date','mobile','opt_out','campaign_id','day_open','priority','tag_ids' ,'purposes_id','day_close', 'title',  'pricelist_id' ,'referred','partner_latitude', 'create_date', 'partner_longitude','stage_id','type']"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `list_items_detailed` and `zb.jason.controller`? Could you share the code? Why don't you use provided ORM methods like `search` or maybe better for your call `search_read`. Both have parameters for limit, offset and "order by". `search_read` will take a list of fields, like in your args.